# Postmates API not working - "ForbiddenError"

Tags: php, api, rest, postmates

We are using postmates API for grocery app. We are using their test credentials, but I don't know how to use it. Kindly guide me how can I make a basic API call. I am using PHP. And want to know which is correct API key to pass in header. Thank in advance!

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();
$username = "1f37d2fb-****-4689-****-****57e****"; // sandbox key from postmates developer account
$password = ""; // left this blank, as per the doc

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.postmates.com/v1/customers/my-customer-key/delivery_quotes',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('pickup_address' => '76 9th Ave, New York, NY','dropoff_address' => '76 9th Ave, New York, NY'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Basic Y2YyZjJkNmQtYTMxNC00NGE4LWI2MDAtNTA1M2MwYWYzMTY1Og==' // Got this from postmates documentation
  ),
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
?>
```

When I run this PHP in postman I got this error:

```
{
    "kind": "error",
    "code": "forbidden",
    "message": "ForbiddenError"
}
```

Kindly guide me how to use postmates api. thanks

Comment: Is that the actual URL you're sending to or did you replace `my-customer-key` with your key?

Comment: I will replace my-customer-key with my key which is generated when I signed up postmates developer Account(eg: cus_nwe****Sas)